# How can I change the way the comma is compiled?

Tags: punctuation

[[image: comma as decimal point separator, after 1902]

[image: comma after "CB"]

I am using:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

The problem is that when I compile the text, comma appears as decimal point separator. How can I change this ?

Comment: This depends on your preamble. Which packages do you use? Can you post a minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I suggest you use a package like `siunitx` to typeset your numeric constants.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal complete example?

Comment: The code you posted alone can't explain what happens.

Comment: by default a comma will typeset as a comma, so you must have some code to change that. You need to remove that code but if you give no clues we can not tell you what to remove.

Comment: Do you load the `babel` package? If so, which language options have you set?

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply @Bernard   . I will be more especific this time. I have just put two photos  for an example. One of the images, show the comma as i want to. It is after "CB" highlighted in yellow. The other image show my compilation. Can you see the difference, after "1902" ? As i have said earlier, i am not using math type $$. It is on text mode. A friend told me this is a problem with fonts. Can you help, please ?! Regards. Sergio

Comment: After CB there's a standard comma in the Palatino font; in the first picture the font is Latin Modern and the comma is different.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are using package `siunitx`. There both the comma and the period can be used as input decimal markers (see option `input-decimal-markers`). The decimal marker for the output is configured by `output-decimal-marker`, the default is the period and can be changed to a comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\begin{document}
\num{123,456} and \num{42.42}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a ”decimal separator”. What you're seeing are different shapes for the plain comma.

The first picture has text in Latin Modern, as you requested. The second picture has text in Palatino. The two fonts have different shapes for the comma and there's nothing particular about this.

Do `\usepackage{mathpazo}` instead of `\usepackage{lmodern}`. This will change the text font to Palatino, as in the second picture.

---

#### Original answer

I think I have an explanation of your problem. Consider the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

A number: $1.234$

\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

If you want a decimal point, instead of a comma, add the `es-nodecimaldot` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}

\begin{document}

A number: $1.234$

\end{document}
```

[image]

See section 4.1 in the documentation for the Spanish language `babel` module (`texdoc spanish`).